# Posting to Flask with Postman versus requests populates different request attributes

Tags: python, curl, flask, python-requests, postman

I'm sending a POST request to my Flask app with Postman and also the requests library.  When I use Postman, I can get the data with `json.loads(request.data)`.  When I use requests or curl, I can get the data with `request.form`.  Why does sending the same data with the two tools populating different attributes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've used Postman to send the data as JSON, and you've used requests and curl to send it as form data.  You can tell either program to send the data as whatever you expect, rather than letting it use its "default".  For example, you can send JSON with requests:

```
import requests
requests.post('http://example.com/', json={'hello': 'world'})
```

Also note that you can get the JSON directly from the Flask request, without loading it yourself:

```
from flask import request
data = request.get_json()
```

---

`request.data` holds the body of the request, whatever format it may be.  Common types are `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  If the content type was `form-urlencoded`, then `request.form` will be populated with the parsed data.  If it was `json`, then `request.get_json()` will access it instead.

---

If you're really not sure if you'll get the data as a form or as JSON, you could write a short function to try to use one and if that doesn't work use the other.

```
def form_or_json():
    data = request.get_json(silent=True)
    return data if data is not None else request.form

# in a view
data = form_or_json()
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this quote from http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Request explains it:

> **data**
>   A descriptor that calls get_data() and set_data(). This should not be used and will eventually get deprecated.

Comment: My question is why do I need to use `request.data` while using POSTMAN since `request.form` does not works.?  I need to maintain the uniformity. How do I do that?